# How to make a parameterized SELECT query in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, prepared-statement

I'm trying to display data from a table in database using DataGridView and a parameterized query in C# and SQL Server.

So far, I have tried this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Vagtplan;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Ansatte.ansatID = @ansat, Ansatte.Navn = @navn, Ansatte.Efternavn = @efternavn, Ansatte.Adresse = @adresse, Ansatte.Postnummer = @postnummer, Ansatte.Bynavn = @bynavn, Ansatte.Email = @email, Ansatte.Mobilnr = @mobilnr, Login_data.Brugertype = @brugertype FROM Ansatte INNER JOIN Login_data ON Ansatte.ansatID = Login_data.ansatID", con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ansat", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@navn", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@eftervavn", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@adresse", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@postnummer", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@bynavn", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobilnr", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@brugertype", SqlDbType.VarChar);

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

But I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='

How to fix it so I can select data using a parameterized query? Expected result is, that data will be displayed in a DataGridView.

Comment: Why would you need parameters for a broad SELECT query?  Parameters are mainly for protecting your SQL INSERT and UPDATE queries which involve *user input*...unless those are part of a WHERE clause?

Comment: Okey, I just though parameters are useful is SELECT queries as well. So far I use parameters only in INSERT and UPDATE queries , which you have mentioned.

Comment: Parameters are more about *user input* that the query itself - if you had a SELECT...WHERE query with the criteria coming from user input, that would be a good use. `...WHERE foo = @foo`

Comment: Okey, now I understand. Thank you :)

Comment: There are cases when using output parameters is useful. If you are only pulling a single record back, with a small-ish number of fields, then output parameters perform much better than filling an entire datatable. Of course you need to set the parameter direction as `output` and you assign a parameter as `@ParamName = Value` not way you have done it. And you can't bind them like you wish in this case.

Comment: Very unclear what you want to achieve - clearly your SQL statement is wrong (really soo wrong that even humans have hard time guessing what you wanted to do, not just C#/.Net), but fixing it with information you've provided so far is impossible... Maybe you were looking for `WHERE` clause? Maybe you don't need any parameters at all...

Answer (score 4):

You have a few things going on here, and I'll try to break down for you.  Working with a database, you typically do a "select...from..." to get data and "insert into..." to add records to the tables.

Next, your query.  A shortened version of yours..  The problem here is you are trying to assign the @ansat PARAMETER value INTO the Ansatte.ansatID field which is incorrect syntax context to begin with, but review on regardless.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
@"SELECT 
      Ansatte.ansatID = @ansat, 
      Ansatte.Navn = @navn, 
      Ansatte.Efternavn = @efternavn, 
      Ansatte.Adresse = @adresse...
   FROM 
      Ansatte 
         INNER JOIN Login_data 
            ON Ansatte.ansatID = Login_data.ansatID", con);
```

and then adding the parameters...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ansat", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@navn", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@eftervavn", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@adresse", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

Good you are using parameters, but you just DECLARED the parameters, you never assigned any actual values to them, which in essence is resulting in the following getting passed to the engine

```
SELECT 
      Ansatte.ansatID = , 
      Ansatte.Navn = , 
      Ansatte.Efternavn = , 
      Ansatte.Adresse = 
   FROM 
      Ansatte 
         INNER JOIN Login_data 
            ON Ansatte.ansatID = Login_data.ansatID
```

Hence probably your error for no value for the = sign.  Now, to actually add the "Value" to your parameter... Your declaration appeared ok, just finish it with a value that could be a fixed value, from a window entry, config setting, whatever...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ansat", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 123;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@navn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "test";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@eftervavn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "more";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@adresse", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "done";
```

which would result in a protected (non-sql-injection)

Now, what you might really be looking for.  You have a table in your database that you want to pull information from.  In this case, select the columns you WANT, not the values you want to SET.  Just query.  Ex:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
@"SELECT 
      Ansatte.ansatID, 
      Ansatte.Navn, 
      Ansatte.Efternavn, 
      Ansatte.Adresse, 
      Ansatte.Postnummer, 
      Ansatte.Bynavn, 
      Ansatte.Email, 
      Ansatte.Mobilnr, 
      Login_data.Brugertype
   FROM 
      Ansatte 
         INNER JOIN Login_data 
            ON Ansatte.ansatID = Login_data.ansatID", con);
```

If you run the above query, it will return all records that are in the database that have a matching ID between each respective table.

Now, tack on parameters to a SQL-SELECT query.  Say you only wanted all names within a given PostNumber area.  Add a WHERE condition for such field and parameterized value such as

```
   FROM 
      Ansatte 
         INNER JOIN Login_data 
            ON Ansatte.ansatID = Login_data.ansatID
   where
      Ansatte.Postnummer = @MyPostCriteria", con );
      

cmd.Parameters.Add("MyPostCriteria", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 11223;
```

Now, if you are trying to ADD a record TO the database, that would be an insert, and you can only do an insert into a single table at a time and might be something like below.  You identify the table and columns you want to insert, and then the values in the same sequence as their corresponding sequence as added in parenthesis list at the top.. Then parameterize

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
@"INSERT INTO Ansatte
   ( Navn,
     Efternavn,
     Adresse
   )
   values
   ( @parmForNavn,
     @parmForEfternavn,
     @parmForAdresse
   )", con);


    cmd.Parameters.Add("parmForNavn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "test";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("parmForEfternavn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "blah";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("parmForAdresse", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "123 some street";
```

Hopefully this can jump-start you into what you are trying to accomplish from either pulling data down from a database, or insert into.