# 'Input string was not in a correct format.' (update float type in sql server using query)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

```
c.s = "UPDATE produit SET codeBare = '" + tbCodeBare.Text + "',ref = '" + tbRef.Text + "',designation = '" + tbDesignation.Text + "',qte = " + float.Parse(tbQte.Text.Replace(',', '.')) + ", minQte = " + float.Parse(tbMinQte.Text.Replace(',', '.')) + ", puDevis = " + float.Parse(tbPUDevis.Text.Replace(',', '.')) + ", puAchat = " + float.Parse(tbPUAchat.Text.Replace(',', '.')) +" , typeQty = '"+cbTypeQte.Text + "', puVente = " + float.Parse(tbPUVente.Text.Replace(',','.')) + " ,totalEmbalage = '" + tbTotalEmb.Text+ "' WHERE produit.produitID = " + int.Parse(lblIdProduit.Text.ToString()) + "; ";
```

> System.FormatException : 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

When I update table without a `float` column it works, but with a `float` column it does not.

Comment: PLEASE do not use sql injection, you're not only adding security vulnerabilities to your application, you have to deal with things like this format problem. Convert the string in the textbox to a double first, in C# code, then use parameters to pass the value to the server.

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors - _most probably including this one_ - , it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: Are all of the values present?

Comment: Does `qte` represent a quantity? Why would you be using a Base 2 numerical value to store that?

Comment: Is the field in the database defined as a string or a float?  If it is a float then you do not need to convert to a string.

Comment: Use the sql profiler too see what exact is sent to sql server, that will surely give you some idea what is going on. We here cannot help you, we have not enough information for that. It would help if you added the values so we can see the complete query and the table schema

Comment: Please separate the `float.Parse()` to make separate assignments to local variables. Most likely the exception was caused by `float.Parse()` or `int.Parse()`. Even better use `TryParse()`

Comment: If one of the `float.Parse` input strings is empty, then float.Parse will throw the error that you see. Same if it can't parse the string for other reasons. Don't assume that all input is valid - in fact the opposite should be done: **assume all input is *invalid*, unless proven otherwise (by checking it rigorously)**.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:sql] or [tag:sql-server] or [tag:visual-studio], it is purely a C#-side error: the text you are converting is not a float/int. Please don't spam tags

Comment: And again, what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 c.s = "UPDATE produit SET codeBare = @Codebare, ref = @Ref , qty = @Qty , typeQty = @Typeqty,designation = @Designation,minQty = @Minqty ,puDevis = @Pudevis,puAchat = @Puachat,puVente = @Puvente, totalEmbalage = @totalEmbalage  WHERE produit.produitID = @Produitid; ";
          c.cn.Open();


          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(c.s, c.cn);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codebare", tbCodeBare.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ref", tbRef.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", float.Parse(tbQte.Text));
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", tbDesignation.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Minqty", float.Parse(tbMinQte.Text));
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Typeqty", cbTypeQte.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pudevis", float.Parse(tbPUDevis.Text)));
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Puachat", float.Parse(tbPUAchat.Text));
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Puvente", float.Parse(tbPUVente.Text));
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalEmbalage", tbTotalEmb.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Produitid", int.Parse(lblIdProduit.Text));
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, as Franz Gleichmann said in the comments please use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55978404/3090544) to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Otherwise to come to your questions:

- For readability it is common to use line breaks for large lines.
- Please separate the `float.Parse()` and `int.Parse()` to make separate assignments to local variables.

Most likely the exception was caused by `float.Parse()` and if you do separate assignments you will see exactly which textbox input was invalid.

First:

```
c.s = "UPDATE produit SET codeBare = '" + tbCodeBare.Text + 
    "',ref = '" + tbRef.Text + 
    "',designation = '" + tbDesignation.Text + 
    "',qte = " + float.Parse(tbQte.Text.Replace(',', '.')) + 
    ", minQte = " + float.Parse(tbMinQte.Text.Replace(',', '.')) + 
    ", puDevis = " + float.Parse(tbPUDevis.Text.Replace(',', '.')) + 
    ", puAchat = " + float.Parse(tbPUAchat.Text.Replace(',', '.')) + 
    " , typeQty = '" + cbTypeQte.Text + 
    "', puVente = " + "" + float.Parse(tbPUVente.Text.Replace(',', '.')) + 
    " ,totalEmbalage = '" + tbTotalEmb.Text + 
    "' WHERE produit.produitID = " + int.Parse(lblIdProduit.Text.ToString()) + "; ";
```

End then:

```
NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");

bool parseSuccess = float.TryParse(tbDesignation.Text, style, culture, out float theDesignation);
parseSuccess = parseSuccess && float.TryParse(tbQte.Text.Replace, style, culture, out float theQte);
parseSuccess = parseSuccess && float.TryParse(tbMinQte.Text, style, culture, out float theMinQte);
parseSuccess = parseSuccess && float.TryParse(tbPUDevis.Text, style, culture, out float thePUDevis);
parseSuccess = parseSuccess && float.TryParse(tbPUAchat.Text, style, culture, out float thePUAchat);
parseSuccess = parseSuccess && float.TryParse(tbPUVente.Text, style, culture, out float thePUVente);
parseSuccess = parseSuccess && int.TryParse(lblIdProduit.Text.ToString(), out int theIdProduit);

if (!parseSuccess)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong input");
    return;
}

c.s = "UPDATE produit SET codeBare = '" + tbCodeBare.Text + 
    "',ref = '" + tbRef.Text + 
    "',designation = '" + theDesignation + 
    "',qte = " + theQte + 
    ", minQte = " + theMinQte + 
    ", puDevis = " + thePUDevis + 
    ", puAchat = " + thePUAchat + 
    " , typeQty = '" + cbTypeQte.Text + 
    "', puVente = " + "" + thePUVente + 
    " ,totalEmbalage = '" + tbTotalEmb.Text + 
    "' WHERE produit.produitID = " + lblIdProduit + "; ";
```