# .NET - getting the data between two dates

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to get data between two dates from SQL Server.

I try it with this code:

```cs
string kayit = "SELECT * FROM Kabin_Verileri WHERE Readtime BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value + "'";
```

but it get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDWiI.png)

[My SQL Server table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ihFc.png)

Does someone have an idea how to get data between two dates?

Comment: The right way to address this issue is to use a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978404/how-to-make-a-parameterized-select-query-in-c), which makes date format moot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format the `dateTimePicker1.Value` and `dateTimePicker2.Value` to strings that sql can read as
a date. ISO format 'yyyy-mm-dd' would be ideal for most sql engines.

in c# you do this...

```
string fromDateStringISO = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value).ToString('o');
string toDateStringISO = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Value).ToString('o');

string kayit = "SELECT * FROM Kabin_Verileri where Readtime BETWEEN '" + fromDateStringISO + "' and '" + toDateStringISO  + "'"
```

'o' format is ISO format. [Check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0)

Comment: I was using smalldatetime type in table so i used "s" property. Thanks for your solution, its solved!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change varchar data type to a datetime. If dateTimePicker is datetime property you can write it down as dateTimePicker (no need to get its value).

```
string kayit = "SELECT * FROM Kabin_Verileri where Readtime BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1 + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2 + "'";
```

If dateTimePicker is not DateTime property then you need to convert it like @nazim said above

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But nazims idea solved my problem.