# How can I delete from database without the key?

Tags: c#, sql, primary-key, sql-delete

I have a `cart` table that has `cartId` as the primary key, `userId` and `itemId`. I want to delete every row that has the id of a given user

Let's say this is my table:

| cartId | userId | itemID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 5 | 111 |
| 02 | 5 | 112 |
| 03 | 4 | 111 |

I want to delete the information regarding user 5, so my table will look like this:

| cartId | userId | itemID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03 | 4 | 111 |

I have trid this SQL:

```
public static bool DeleteItemsFromCartByUserId(int userId) 
{
    string sql = string.Format("delete from [cart] where [userId] = {0}", userId);
    return Dbf.UpdateTable(sql) == 1;
}
```

```
public static int UpdateTable(string sql)
{
    OleDbConnection obj = Dbf.GenerateConnection();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, obj);
    int value = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    obj.Close();
    return value;
}
```

Every other delete sql that I wrote works perfectly fine - it returns true and deletes the information, but this one returns false and doesn't delete for some reason.

How can I do it if I don't have the cardId's?

Comment: what do you mean by DOES NOT WORK ? please be clear and concise

Comment: Please expand on [it doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) What does this mean? do you get an error? Show your actual code - what debugging steps have you done?

Comment: How are you executing the SQL query string

Comment: Strictly speaking in terms of SQL, `DELETE FROM cart WHERE userId = 5;` should work. Providing your full C# code would be useful. "How can I do it if I don't have the cardId's?" - you don't need the cartIds. Deleting by userId is perfectly valid. What you've provided simply generates a String though. How are you telling your application to execute that string as a SQL statement?

Comment: It's also better to use parameterized queries to prevent injections (possibly from your own bad data), this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978404/how-to-make-a-parameterized-select-query-in-c

Answer (score 2):

[`OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) returns the number of rows that were affected by the command. In your example, you are deleting two rows, but only checking if one row is affected, hence the FALSE return value.

A moderately better check would be:

```
return Dbf.UpdateTable(sql) > 0;
```

However you are still missing some best practices regarding SQL queries in C#, namely:

- Use of SQL parameters instead of formatting/concatenating SQL strings
- Disposing of connections and commands
- Proper error handling

You probably would have also seen this if you stored the result in a variable and checked it in the debugger rather than inlining the function call and the comparison in a `return` statement.